# uiBinder on Button Clickevent

Tags: gwt, uibutton, uibinder

I'm trying to use uiBinder. I followed the tutorial provided by
google, but I don't know why clickevent doesn't work? I want to count number of clicks and show it in the span, it doesn't work, I also put window.alert but it seems that the event handler is not called at all! Can anyone help me? It's couple of hours I'm working on it but can't find the problem!

Thank you so much

P.S.
Below is my code

---

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
   xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
   <ui:style>
   </ui:style>
   <g:HTMLPanel>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img ui:field='imgPrd'/></td>
            <td>
               <span ui:field='lblNum'></span>
                <g:Button ui:field='btnAdd'></g:Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </g:HTMLPanel>
```

---

```
public class uiProductList extends Composite {

@UiField Button btnAdd;
@UiField ImageElement imgPrd;
@UiField SpanElement lblNum;

int count;
private static uiProductListUiBinder uiBinder =
GWT.create(uiProductListUiBinder.class);

interface uiProductListUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget,
uiProductList> {
}

public uiProductList() {
   initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}


@UiHandler("btnAdd")
void handleClick(ClickEvent e) {
  Window.alert("test");
  count++;       
  lblNum.setInnerText(Integer.toString(count));
 }

}
```

Comment: Does the code work if you add a click handler the "regular" way, with `addClickHandler()`?

Comment: Are you sure you're closing the `<ui:UiBinder>` tag? It seems to be missing in the above code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should correctly add your widget to the root panel. Use

> RootPanel.get().add(uiProduct);

Otherwise the handlers are not initialized.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and here is the conclusion:

`RootPanel.getBodyElement().appendChild(uiProduct.getElement());` - **NOT WORKING**

`RootPanel.get().add(uiProduct);` - **WORKING FINE**